# Rolling data based on custom function - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to create a DataFrame that contains daily entries of values that are based on a rolling 12 month slice of larger data sets (called applications and assignments). At the moment, I have not used df.rolling because I don't think it's right in this situation. I am simply looping through an index of dates, performing several functions on a 12 month slice of the larger data sets for each date. The returned values are then appended to a list for each variable, then I create a DataFrame using those lists. This is slow.

I am looking for a ways to speed up the creation of my rolling_data DataFrame.

This is the function that calculates the values from a rolling window:

```
def calculate_rolling(apps, assgs, date_index):

    # dictionary containing lists of data - used later to create df
    values = {'owners':[],
              'successful_owners' :[],
              'applications' :[],
              'assignments':[],
              'filled_assignments':[],
              'sitters':[],
              'successful_sitters':[]
        }

    for day in date_index:
        twelve_months_prior = day - relativedelta(months=12)

        app_view = apps.loc[str(twelve_months_prior):str(day.date())] # slice of applications df
        assg_view = assgs.loc[str(twelve_months_prior):str(day.date())] # slice of assignments df

        values['owners'].append(assg_view.ouser_id.nunique())
        values['sitters'].append(assg_view.ouser_id.nunique())
        values['applications'].append(app_view.request_id.count())
        values['assignments'].append(assg_view.is_assignment_filled.sum())
        values['filled_assignments'].append(assg_view.is_assignment_filled.sum())
        values['successful_sitters'].append(assg_view[assg_view.is_assignment_filled ==1].suser_id.nunique())
        values['successful_owners'].append(assg_view[assg_view.is_assignment_filled ==1].ouser_id.nunique())

    return pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=date_index)
```

..and this is how I am calling that, after creating the date range index:

```
# create index of dates
index = pd.date_range(start=start, end=applications.created_date.max())

# create df from values dictionary
rolling_data = calculate_rolling(applications, assignments, index)
```

%timeit gives me 23 secs to process calculate_rolling_data() at the moment. This will cause me problems when using this in my Bokeh dashboard.

### Sample data

Sample data - applications:

```
    request_id  req_type    assignment_id   date_created    last_modified   oid sid ouser_id    suser_id    oconfirmed  sconfirmed  aid created_date
    0   30682   app 42  2016-04-13  2016-04-13  828 2329    1360    4822    0   1   42.0    2016-04-13
    1   5718    app 52  2016-03-17  2016-03-17  220 18435   339 27455   1   1   NaN NaT
    2   5719    app 75  2016-03-17  2016-03-17  639 13645   1027    20691   1   1   75.0    2015-07-21
    3   5720    app 245 2016-03-17  2016-03-17  2324    39096   5529    52883   1   1   NaN NaT
    4   5721    app 262 2016-03-17  2016-03-17  1343    39089   2918    52876   1   1   262.0   2015-08-16
```

Sample data - assignments:

```
    aid created_date    start_date  end_date    oid sid ouser_id    suser_id    is_assignment_filled
created_date                                    
2010-12-18  1   2010-12-18  2010-12-18  2011-03-05  104 NaN 87  NaN False
2010-12-11  2   2010-12-11  2010-12-11  2011-01-02  108 NaN 93  NaN False
2011-08-12  3   2011-08-12  2011-08-12  2011-08-28  1220    NaN 1972    NaN False
2011-01-09  4   2011-01-09  2011-01-09  2011-05-11  323 NaN 482 NaN False
2010-12-28  7   2010-12-28  2010-12-28  2011-01-31  142 NaN 169 NaN False
```

Comment: I don't know why you wouldn't want to use `rolling().apply()` here, this sounds like a standard use case.  It's nice that you showed your work but it would really help if you could show sample data and desired results (and also a simplified version of your function, only as much as needed to demonstrate the concept)

Comment: Fair point @JohnE - the data (applications and assignments) are not a time-series, so I assumed that  rolling() would not create the results I am looking for, especially as I am also trying to get daily rolling totals for a moving 12-month window